# Devise Logout being intercepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm testing my website using Devise, and what I've found is if I intercept the redirect after a Devise Sign Out, while the "destroy" method is being called, I can still use the back button and log back into the system.

A bit more details:

1) I am using Devise with the following options: :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :password_archivable, :maximum_attempts => 4, :unlock_strategy => :none.  Also, I using the default settings for sign_out_all_scopes (true).

2) I am using Burp Proxy to intercept calls coming back to the browser from the server.

3) My Session Controller Destroy method is as follows:

```
def destroy
  Rails.logger.info "RESETTING SESSION"
  reset_session

  Rails.logger.info "DESTROYING DEVISE SESSION"
  super
  Rails.logger.info "DONE WITH DEVISE"    
end
```

The logs calls are just for me, also I have tried with and without the reset_session.

4) I log in as a user, then I click my logout call, I see that the Destroy method is called on the Web Server (looking at the logs), but I intercept the call to the browser.

5) Clicking the back button, I am can get back into the site and I can navigate it like I never was logged out.

It appears to me that despite calling the Warden's logout behind the scenes, it actually do anything unless the cookie is destroyed on the browser.  Also looking a little closer, it doesn't appear that Devise or Warden does anything to the database on logout meaning that logging out yet not destroying the cookie would have no effect anyway.

I'm relatively new to Rails and very new to Devise, so am I just missing something?

EDIT: So after a brief conversation with Billy Chen it seems I'm not doing anything wrong, this is just how Devise/Warden works.

I'm curious how anyone is solving this problem for sites where they want to be assured that logging out really logs out a user?  Throwing in a status on the User object that gets updated on login/logout would be easy enough, but I'm curious why there is no option to do that in the current design (even if it was just optional).

EDIT 2:

Solved the issue.  Despite not having :rememberable turned on in the User model, the devise.rb file had "config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true", removing this fixed the problem.  Not exactly sure why that configuration should be used if the model doesn't allow rememberable, but at least the problem is solved.

EDIT 3:

Apparently I'm a liar, it's not fixed I had just missed intercepting the response in burp proxy.  Retesting show this is still an issue.  Fixing it by tagging the User with a key and removing it on logout.  A hack, but it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "destroy" is to destroy session, not user. So why do you expect database operation in this "destroy" action?

When an user log in, he fill out email and password in login page, aka "Session#new".

When he hit "log in" button, the request is sent to "Session#create". If login info is correct, session established. The server send a cookie containing session id which is hash including user id.

On every requests from this user thereafter, his browser send request together with this cookie. The server decodes this hash and load user id from database.

If he wants to log out, he'll hit "logout" button which will send "DELETE" request to "Session#destroy", then server will ask his browser to delete the key/id from that cookie.

Now the session is destroyed. This user can no more access protected resources for login users, because requests he send thereafter won't contain his valid user info.

That's basically how it works. You can check the details here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: "So why do you expect database operation in this "destroy" action?"

Because basing a security model around the client is incredibly flawed.  Hitting the logout button should tell Warden that any request with the old credentials are invalid. 

Also, clearly the session isn't being destroyed since after reseting the session I can click back and am still in the system.

Comment: @Andrew, I meant you don't need that.

Comment: I understand that the browser is asked to delete the key/id from the cookie, the part I don't understand is why a security system is relying on that?

Comment: To my knowledge I don't know other convenient way to identify an authenticated user, if you don't use cookie or localstorage.

Comment: Clearly there has to be a way, that or rails can't be used for any sort of public system that relies on Security (like a bank), but we know that isn't the case.

The part I don't really get about Devise/Warden is it appears calling warden.logout does nothing other than tells the Browser to remove data from a cookie.  Expecting the Client to handle security is not something I would ever expect is a good idea.

Comment: I see your point after reading full text of first comment. New knowledge learned. And, yes, if the cookie/key is saved elsewhere and got back after logout the session should still be valid. But I think for most web app, security to this extent is good enough.